# How To Filter a Matlab Array of Structs Based Upon The Value Of A Struct field Of Type String

Tags: matlab

I've made an array of structs that contains every file & dir in my parent directory, using

```
allfiles = dir(fullfile('.',"**"));.
```

However, I'm only interested in files named `'data.env'`.

My belief is that the name of every file in the directory tree is contained in the 'name' field of some row of `allfiles` and the path to each file is contained in the 'folder' field. How can I remove all rows from all files, where the name field is not `'data.env'`?

My best attempt has been as follows:

```
ctr=0;
loclist = [];
for ii = 1:size(allfiles)
  if strcmp(allfiles(ii).name,'data.env')
    loclist(ctr+1)=ii;
    ctr=ctr+1;
  end
end
relevantFiles=allfiles(loclist);
```

but, I'm certain there's a more elegant solution that vectorizes my for loop.

Comment: Looks like a pretty good solution to me. A vectorized solution is likely harder to read and not any faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a logical index vector with arrayfun and use that to create the result. E.g.,

```
x = arrayfun(@(k)strcmp(allfiles(k).name,'data.env'),1:numel(allfiles));
relevantFiles = allfiles(x);
```